# Missing logic for <a> creation

Tags: javascript

I currently take baby steps in JS development and coded the following link adder:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
const listdiv = document.querySelector('.listdiv')

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 let input = document.getElementById('text').value

 let createA = document.createElement('a')
 createA.setAttribute('href', input)
 let linkDescr = document.createTextNode(input)
 createA.appendChild(linkDescr)

 listdiv.appendChild(createA)
})
```

The order of instruction is this:

Get the value of the text box

Create `<a>`

Set `<a>`'s link description

Set `href`

**add `<a>`'s description to `<a>`**

And then add all of `<a>` to the pre-existing `Div`..

So far so good. But, why is it that when we set `href`, it gets automatically added to `<a>`, but we have to take an extra step to add the link's description? Isn't `let linkDescr = document.createTextNode(input)` supposed to add the description automatically as well? My theory is that the commands are different in that we directly set an attribute of `<a>` for one, but create a variable on the other; and something need's to be done first with this variable. Variables don't just do anything by themselves. Please educate me on my logic. Also feel free to propose code changes/suggestions/flaws.
Thank you

Comment: `Isn't let linkDescr = document.createTextNode(input) supposed to add the description automatically as well?` how would you write code if you want to create separate unrelated element then?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Your question = my question?! This seems to be the way to add an unrelated element since you can use `createTextNode` anywhere in the document. I don't understand your question

Comment: exactly, there is nothing in this line which tells `add the description automatically`, so this is the way to create independent element, which of course should be related by some other code like `appendChild`

Answer (score 1):

There are often multiple ways to do things.

For example, the `href` can be added like this:

```
createA.href = input;
```

So then the description can also be added as a property.

```
createA.textContent = input;
```

The API simply gives us the choice. Appending a text node may make more sense in some cases, like when you're relocating an existing node.

In your case, you're creating a new text node. This is an object that is independent of any other part of the DOM tree, so it doesn't do anything until you insert it in the position where you want it, like inside the new `a` element.

Comment: I think you meant `createA.textContent = **input**`. But other than that it makes sense. I didn't use this because I didn't know about the `textContent` command. Thank you!